# Heatmap in GNU Plot

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I have a following file with data.

> ```
>  x   y    z
> 100 123   1
> 123 345   1
> 78  234   1
> 100 123   2
> 12   1    1
> ...
> ...
> ...
> ```

I would like to present this data in a Heatmap using GNU Plot this is array 400x400 and z represent the density. How Can I import file with data and present in gnuplot as a heatmap?

Comment: What is the reason for the `Python` tag?

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes. i havent seen this question before. pardon